# How to get product image by product Id in magento2

Tags: magento2, product, product-images, catalog

I am not able to get the absolute path of the image by product id in Magento 2. Can anybody help me?

I am able to get media path so far by **directoryList** class by doing this:

```
$this->directory->getPath('media');
```

How to get product image full path?

Please note that I don't want an image URL, I want the image path directory.

Comment: Please upload your file code. which you tried to get image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Product image path from `Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeMediaGalleryManagementInterface`
If you have sku then from this interface's getList() you get media image.

from media image you get image path.

```
<?php
/**
 * User: amit-pc
 * Date: 1/1/19
 */

namespace Devbera\Test;


class Test
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeMediaGalleryManagementInterface
     */
    private $productAttributeMediaGalleryManagement;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeMediaGalleryManagementInterface $productAttributeMediaGalleryManagement
    )
    {

        $this->productAttributeMediaGalleryManagement = $productAttributeMediaGalleryManagement;
    }
    public function getMediaPath()
    {
        $media = $this->productAttributeMediaGalleryManagement->getList($sku = 'ab2');
        foreach ($media as $image)
        {
            print_r(['value_id' => $image->getId(),
            'file' => $image->getFile(),
            'label' => $image->getLabel(),
            'position' => $image->getPosition(),
            'disabled' => $image->isDisabled(),
            'types' => $image->getTypes(),
            'media_type' => $image->getMediaType()
                ]);
            echo $image->getFile();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below code

```
     $itemsid = 2;
     $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($itemsid);
        echo $imageUrl = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image')
                                                    ->init($product, 'product_base_image')
                                                    ->constrainOnly(TRUE)
                                                    ->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
                                                    ->keepTransparency(TRUE)
                                                    ->keepFrame(FALSE)
                                                    ->resize(150, 150)->getUrl();
```

Comment: what is $this->helper here

Comment: here is i am  used the Image helper

Comment: you can get more information about helper is here....

https://belvg.com/blog/how-to-use-helper-in-magento-2-0-template.html

Comment: @nirmesh tell me helpfull code for you or not